# arrange a meeting + conformation

Tags: english-to-german

Date and time were discussed last week but I would like to know if they have any changes (conformation). I am not sure if I can directly translate … if it  works

**Eng version:**

Please let me know If there are any changes in your schedule.

I’m flexible if something else works better

**DE version**

Geben Sie mir bitte Bescheid, wenn Ihr Zeitplan sich ändert.

Ich bin flexibel, wenn etwas anderes besser funktioniert

**EDIT :**

Can i add smth like this: wie es im Freitag besprochen wurde, habe ich eine Beschprechung via Outlook erstellt?

Answer (score 4):

I assume it is a business-like appointment, so some formality is appropriate. Your translation is quite good, but the subclause of the second sentence has a somewhat unidiomatic touch, which can be improved by changing it to:

> ... wenn Ihnen ein anderer Termin besser passt.

I nevertheless make another proposal:

> Bitte geben Sie mir Bescheid, wenn Ihnen etwas dazwischen kommt. Derzeit kann ich noch einige Termine zum Ausweichen anbieten.

Comment: Can i add smth like this: wie es im Freitag besprochen wurde, habe ich eine Besprechung via Outlook erstellt?

Comment: @AnnaKoroleva: Yes, but it should probably read: "wie **am** Freitag besprochen, habe ich eine Outlook-Besprechung (dazu) erstellt". But I'm wondering, what benefit this addition has, since any recipient will get the Outlook invitation anyway?

Answer (score 2):

It will work and be understood but is not very idiomatic.

Though personally I don't consider schedule well translated. In this context the better literal translation would be 'Ihre Zeitplanung' or 'Ihre Termine sich ändern'

On the more idiomatic side, I'd go with

> Bitte geben Sie Bescheid, wenn Sie Terminprobleme haben. Ich bin zeitlich flexibel.

Or

> Bitte melden Sie sich bei Terminproblemen. Ich bin zeitlich flexibel.